# Проблема запуска проекта на Nuxt.js

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

создала проект на Nuxt.js через команду yarn create nuxt-app . После завершения создания проекта пытаюсь запустить проект и в консоли появляется ошибка:
✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Error: @nuxtjs/tailwindcss tried to access pathe, but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.                                                                 Required package: pathe (via "pathe\package.json")                                                                  Required by: @nuxtjs/tailwindcss@npm:5.3.5 (via                                                                     D:\Projects\site\first-nuxt-project.yarn\cache@nuxtjs-tailwindcss-npm-5.3.5-4d5936d89f-e47927f9f1.zip\node_mod   ││   ules@nuxtjs\tailwindcss\dist\module.mjs)

Yarn verssion: 3.6.1.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "first-nuxt-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.3.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.1.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.17",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обнови зависимости в пакете **package.json** До последней версии.